# How to find some $C^\infty$ functions that do not satisfy the uniqueness theorem for analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

The uniqueness theorem for analytic functions states that suppose two series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n$ and$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nx^n$ converges in the interval $(-R,R)$. If the set of $x$ that satisfies
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_nx^n$$
has a limit point in the interval, then $s_n=t_n$ for all $n \in N$. I know there are lots of functions which are infinitely differentiable but not analytic, such as the one in the wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function, but I do not know how to use these functions to give a counterexample of the uniqueness theorem. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Use the $f(x)$ given on the Wikipedia page and consider $f(x)$ and $f(x/2)$. They're equal on all of $(-\infty,0]$, but none of $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Meelo Oh I see, thx! Then I can find a sequence with limit point that f(x)=f(x/2) but their Taylor series are definitely not the same. Am I right?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what question you are asking. Any power series that converges on $(-R,R)$ is analytic with convergence radius $R$, which is why John gave you his answer. If you are asking whether there are two $C^\infty$ functions that agree on a convergent sequence but are not the same (as a function, and not comparing any coefficients), then *Meelo*'s comment would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that to give a counterexample. The theorem assume already that the two series converge in an interval. Thus they are both analytic functions (Not only smooth) on that interval.